# NGINX Reverse Proxy Multiple NodeJS Apps On Same Domain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've recently setup an Ubuntu Server to host several NodeJS applications internally for our company.  The applications all reside at the same domain (alpha.domain.com), but on different ports.  The applications are served with ExpressJS (as they also act as an API).

I'm trying to setup NGINX to reverse proxy these ExpressJS/NodeJS applications but am struggling hard.  I've followed every tutorial I can find but they don't seem solve my problem, or I am clearly not understanding what I am doing.  I'm a front-end developer filling in for our dev-ops guy who recently left the company.

My server is at:  alpha.domain.com (internal DNS forwards to static IP server)

My NGINX config is currently:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name alpha.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        server_name alpha.domain.com www.alpha.domain.com;

        location /pnl {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Each application is a ReactJS application that will be served with ExpressJS/PM2.  I want NGINX to ***only*** reverse proxy these urls in such a way that:

- **alpha.domain.com/pnl** loads to https://localhost:5000
- **alpha.domain.com/2d** loads to https://localhost:5001
- etc...

If I change the location in the above server block to simply `/`, then the application at `https://localhost:5000` works fine.  Having it at `/pnl` causes all of my static assets (from Create-React-App build) to `404`.

ExpressJS is (trimmed non-important bits):

```
let app = express()

const KEY = fs.readFileSync("path_to_key")
const CERT = fs.readFileSync("path_to_cert")
const PORT = 5000

app.use(express.static("build"))

// handle SPA application routing (routing done client side)
app.get("/*", function (_, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build/index.html"), (err) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(err)
  })
})

const httpsServer = https.createServer({ key: KEY, cert: CERT }, app)
httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at https://alpha.domain.com:${PORT}`)
})
```

Here is my file structure:

```
├── build
│   ├── asset-manifest.json
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── precache-manifest.12d9913d64add6e70d8bdc1e6f5fa0aa.js
│   ├── service-worker.js
│   └── static
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── 2.d26be9bd.chunk.css
│       │   └── main.86152b9d.chunk.css
│       ├── js
│       │   ├── 2.d769608a.chunk.js
│       │   ├── 2.d769608a.chunk.js.LICENSE.txt
│       │   ├── main.b32be59d.chunk.js
│       │   └── runtime~main.afeea630.js
│       └── media
│           └── logo.4d542fd5.svg
├── index.js
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

Any guidance on how to solve this problem?

**- EDIT -**

Here is the contents of the index.html which is generated by ReactJS.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
        <title>Part Number Log</title>
        <link href="/static/css/2.d26be9bd.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/main.86152b9d.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="/static/js/runtime~main.afeea630.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/2.d769608a.chunk.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/js/main.b32be59d.chunk.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the application server on 5000 expect a request URL starting with /pnl ?  BTW, why https between Nginx and NodeJS?   If someone can intercept that, you'll have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: What is the root of your file structure?   What's above build? (or beneath).

Comment: Regarding HTTPS between Nginx and Node - I was initially just going to serve the express app, I'll correct this if I stick with Nginx.  The only thing above build is an `index.js` which is my ExpressJS  server and the `node_modules` and `package.json` associated with that.  The application server on 5000 does not expect a url starting with `/pnl`. Navigating to `https://alpha.domain.com:5000` loads the application correctly (including resources like css/js).

Comment: Is /build the full path or is it /var/www/reactjs/npl/build or something like that.

Comment: The ExpressJS application is serving from:  `/home/user/pnl-server/build`.  Server is started from this directory so the path to just `build` resolves.  I'm also toying with serving the static files directly from NGINX and just using Express for my API, perhaps that is the easier approach?

Comment: Yes, but how will you distinguish between the static content of different applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your config

```
        location /pnl {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:5000/;
```

/pnl is removed from the URL and replaced by /.
Try

```
        location /pnl/static/ {
            alias /home/user/pnl-server/build/static
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /pnl {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:5000;
```

[nginx proxy_pass directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In doing this, the `index.html` loads, however, I am not being properly served the `/static/*` content.  An example of one of the `404` files path is: `/static/css/main.86152b9d.chunk.css`.  If I manually navigate to `https://localhost:5000` everything works fine.  Also using NGINX with the location of `/` works fine.

Comment: What is the URL for the /static requests?  There's nothing in Nginx's config regarding /static.

Comment: I've made an edit to my initial post with the contents of the `index.html` file generated by ReactJS.  The html loads, but each of these resource files return a 404 after the reverse proxy when the location is anything other than `location / { ... }`.

Comment: Can you add a "homepage": "https : / /your.fqdn/pnl"  to the reactjs package.json?

Comment: Might be making some progress here.  Added your suggestion and did a new build.  NGINX is now finding the files, but its transferring them as text and I am getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.  There is a warning for the CSS: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

Comment: Scratch that, hit refresh and getting Bad Gateway 502 error.

Comment: I'm quite sure it's not Nginx but ReactJS that's serving those files as text. But I believe you can now let Nginx serve those files.  Can Nginx read  /home/user/pnl-server/build ?

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this, you're solution of adding the extra `/pnl/static/` location did the trick.